# Doctrine mapping not recognized with more complex hierarchy

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, php-8

Given the following entity hierachy:

```
// in main project src/Entity
#[ORM\Entity]
class Article extends AbstractArticle
```

```
// in bundle src/Entity/Content
#[ORM\MappedSuperclass]
abstract class AbstractArticle extends AbstractEntity
```

```
// in bundle src/Entity
#[ORM\MappedSuperclass]
abstract class AbstractEntity implements NormalizableInterface, EntityInterface
```

And this configuration:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
        XyBundle:
            is_bundle: true
            type: annotation
            dir: 'Entity'
            prefix: 'XyBundle\Entity'
            alias: Xy
```

I'm getting this error:

`Class "App\Entity\Article" sub class of "XyBundle\Entity\Content\AbstractArticle" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.`

I want to instantiate one or more different articles of the abstract article in the future. Yet, this configuration works if and only if I put `#[ORM\Entity]` to the AbstractArticle class.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I backtracked the issue to the point that I had to change the mapping type to `attribute` instead of `annotation`. It works now.